# No policy for murder?

Tags: prison-architect

Why their is no policy punishment for murder in this game? My assassin just end-up with the punishment for "agravated injury"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Murderers who are caught within your prison are automatically punished with:

- Additional 25 years on their sentence
- Upgrading of their security category
- The usual policy punishments you have set up for *attacked prisoner*, *attacked staff*, *found weapons* etc. depending on how the killing went down.

The first two are hard coded and can't be changed by policy in the base game.  The upgrading of security category will not raise prisoners above maximum security.

**As of Version 2 these penalties are customisable through the prison policy menu.**

Comment: Upping to SuperMax is only manual, the game does not automatically do that, as was described in the Alpha video that introduced the feature